# Download photo from Facebook album

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is it possible and legal for a website to download and store photos from a Facebook album?

This the process that I'mtrying to achieve from my website.

- A user browses to my website
- My website uses the Facebook SDK to display the user's Facebook photos
- The user selects photos
- My website physically downloads those selected photos and stores them on the server that the website is hosted on.

I need to download these photos so that other users can see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's technically possible if you ask for the correct permissions when you authenticate.

Facebook allows you to download user data (including photos) for purposes of *caching*.

There are a lot of responsibilities that come along with being able to download user data and rather than trust my interpretation, you should really read the [Facebook Policy](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/) yourself.